# add roles command not working (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I am Coding my own discord bot for my server, I have a issue that the bot says no role doesn't exit even if I mentions the role. Here is the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on("message", message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

if (command === "add") {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES"))
            return message.channel.send("Insufficient permissions")
        const member = message.mentions.members.first()
        if (!member)
            return message.channel.send("No user mentioned")
        const add = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if (!add)
            return message.channel.send("No role said")
        const roleAdd = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === add);
        if (!roleAdd)
            return message.channel.send("Role does not exist")
            if (member.roles.has(roleAdd.id)){
            return message.channel.send("User already has role")
            }
        if (member) {
            member.addRole(roleAdd).catch((error) =>{
                message.channel.send("I cant add...")
            }).then((member) => {
                message.channel.send(`:thumbsup: ${roleAdd} added to ${member.displayName}`)
            })

        }
    }

})

client.login(config.token)
```

What did I made a mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you are using discord.js v12. Type `npm i discord.js@latest` in your terminal. [Here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html) you can see all changes in discord.js v12.

If you are using discord.js v12 now, this code should work for you:

```js
if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES"))
   return message.channel.send("Insufficient permissions")
const member = message.mentions.members.first()
if (!member)
   return message.channel.send("No user mentioned")
const add = args.slice(1).join(" ");
if (!add)
   return message.channel.send("No role said")
const roleAdd = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === add);
if (!roleAdd)
   return message.channel.send("Role does not exist")
if (member.roles.cache.has(roleAdd.id)) {
   return message.channel.send("User already has role")
}
if (member) {
  member.roles.add(roleAdd).catch((error) => {
     message.channel.send("I cant add...")
   }).then((member) => {
       message.channel.send(`:thumbsup: ${roleAdd} added to ${member.displayName}`)
   })
}
```

Mention the role you want to add won't work because here

```js
const roleAdd = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === add);
```

you just find the role by its name. To fix that you can change that line into:

```js
const roleAdd = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === add) || message.mentions.roles.first();
```

This will allow a user to mention the role as well.

Comment: Oh man! I made a mistake!! The code I pasted is my old code :( I am using the code you gave, working on it.

Comment: @ChoppyMaster can you give me an example, how you are using the command?

Comment: Me:    ".add @user @role"    Bot:   "Role not found."     Actually the mentioned role is there.

Comment: if you tag the role you need to add the line that I used in my answer, I explained that there. @ChoppyMaster